# display a cross-hair within a picture with python3

Tags: display, python-3, framebuffer

I want to add a cross-hair pointing to a position within a picture frame and display it. How could this be done effectively using python3? Which library would be preferable?

Comment: Is the position fixed, is the frame rate high? is it 480 x 320 black and white? And shall I use OpenCV or tensorFlow to look up the cat or dog to cross-hair?

Comment: This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Ingo: Well I have problems on the RPi, not on my Ubuntu. I guess there is something special with it, that's why I dare to ask here.

Comment: @tlfong01: frame rate might be slow, 5 to 10 pic/sec would be sufficient. Color would be better for recognition, bw is also fine. Had problems to install OpenCV, camera signal was not recognized. My post which asked for a proven solution in a less detailed queston was rejected by other members. No cats or dogs, but pcb-drills and vias will be cross-haired, or is corss-wire more suitable then ;c)

Comment: Hi @peets, thank you for your confirmation. I am not surprised  that your vague question is not popular, because it is too board. Let me doing some brainstorming.

Comment: (1) If your a bit board, a bit project like big question can be split into smaller questions, as the StackOverflow management always recommends: "Be laser sharp focus on a particular topic". Eg I have been trying to answer specific questions like this "Me Rpi4B, buster 2020feb05 here. me problem is installing OpenCV according to the following  tutorials, below are the error messages.  I have also tried the following other gitHubs/blogs, but no luck, ...", then I think more OpenCV guys are happy to help, share experience, and learn together. / to continue, ...